# add quotation marks to a string in C to use with fopen

Tags: c

I'm writing some code to create a file and save some text to it.
I use `fopen` to open my file.
In `fopen` the name of the file must be like : "name.txt".
The program asks for a name and an extension for the file.
I save the name and extension to a different string.
What I want to do is make a new string and add my other two strings to this in a format like: "name.extension"
My input is `name` and `extension`. 
So I need to add the quotation marks and the point in between them.

I already tried some of the things replied on this post but nothing works for now. 
I guess there is also an issue with the free space left in my string to use with `fopen`?

This is my code:

```
    char n[BUFSIZ];
    char x[BUFSIZ];
    char naam[BUFSIZ];

    printf("\nGeef een naam voor het bestand in: ");//name for file
    scanf("%s", n);
    printf_s("\nGeef een extensie in voor de file: ");//extension for file
    scanf("%s", x);
    strcat(naam, """");  
    strcat(naam, n);
    strcat(naam, ".");
    strcat(naam, x);
    puts(naam);


    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(naam, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("het bestand kon niet correct worden aangemaakt\n");

        printf("werkt niet\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
```

EDIT:

So I solved my string. The first one needed to be a strcpy.
When I print `naam` the output seems fine but I'm still having an error when opening the file.

This is the code:

```
char n[BUFSIZ];
char x[BUFSIZ];
char naam[BUFSIZ];
printf("\nGeef een naam voor het bestand in: ");//name for file
scanf("%s", n);
printf_s("\nGeef een extensie in voor de file: ");//extensio for file
scanf("%s", x);

strcpy(naam, "\"");
strcat(naam, n);
strcat(naam, ".");
strcat(naam, x);
strcat(naam, "\"");
printf("%s", naam);

FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen(naam, "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("De file kon niet correct worden geschreven\n");
    getchar();
    exit(1);
}
```

Thanks to everyone for the support!

Comment: Filenames normally don't contain `"`. Are you sure about this?

Comment: fopen uses "filename"

Comment: To open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\bla.txt` use `fopen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\bla.txt", ...);`. Mind the "double" back slashes.

Comment: No, `fopen` simply takes a string that contains the filename. `fopen` doesn't care about quotes.

Comment: if there are no quotes in the filename "fopen" won't open the file... So i guess 'fopen' does care about the quotes

Comment: You are probably misinterpreting the results you get. Dare to show the failing code?

Comment: It is suspicious that the first call is `strcat()` and not `strcpy()`.  Yet without a complete example, the post is unclear.  Add more code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Example:in `printf("het bestand kon niet correct worden aangemaakt\n");` , the quotes are *not* part of the string, they are only syntax-elements to delimit it; after the printf() there are no `"` characters visible on the screen. Does your filename *really* contains `"` characters?

Comment: "*still having an error when opening the file*" most likely because the file name does **not** start and end with a double quote (`"`).

Comment: Also assuming "*geschreven*" means "written", the error occurred while "opening" the file, not while writing to it.

Comment: @alk.: Why do we need that `"` ? Given that if we pass a string it would open it.

Comment: No my file name does not contain quotation marks. As in all the examples fopen is used like `fopen("test.txt","w")`. I wan't to replace this with a string like `fopen(naam,"w")`.

Comment: @michielreyntjens.: That;s what I said precisely. In my answer. If you check the edit Just put the name in the string ...concat dot and then extension..everything works

Comment: @coderredoc: With "*file name*" I was referring to the "real" file name, as per the file system.

Comment: BTW `printf_s()` is nonsense. IMnsvHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strcat(naam,"\"\"");
```

This is the way. You have to escape them so that they are considered pass of the string literal.

If you want it around the filename then `sprintf` is the way to go.

Also it is not clear why you want to concatenate then in the `naam`.

If `naam` is something like this `filename.txt` then it will be after putting any of these operations mentioned above will be

`"filename.txt"` or `filename.txt""`.

You can do it more clearly given the context that it will be used in `fopen`.

```
const char *filename = "file.txt";
FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
```

**Edit** (Yes  this is for illustration - `strcpy` etc are used)

For the OP the correct code would be

```
strcpy(naam, n);
strcat(naam, ".");
strcat(naam, x);
...
if ((fp = fopen(naam, "w+")) == NULL){
     fprintf(fp,"Hello world");
}
fclose(fp);
```